If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum \ln(1+a_n)$ converge, does $\sum a_n^2$ converge?

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence with the property $a_n>-1$ for all $n$. Assume $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ converge. Must $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ converge also?

The Taylor polynomial of degree $2$ of $\ln(1+x)$ around $0$ is $x-\frac {x^2}{2}$, so in the opposite direction to the one requested, the convergence of both $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^2$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ would imply convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$. However I couldn't find a way to manipulate the series to get the direction in the question. I also tried the sequence $a_n= \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$, but it doesn't seem that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln(1+a_n)$ converges. How shall one continue?

You can use the fact that when $x$ is small $x^2\le 3(x-\ln(1+x))$ and $a_n$ is small eventually.

@JetfiRex This is not true if $x<0$

@Yathi Are you sure? For the case $x<0$ the rhs is even larger then that for $x>0$.

You are right. I just had taken $x^2-x+\ln(1+x)$. $x^2-kx+k\ln(1+x)<0$ for small $x$ for any $k>1$.

Adding this comment motivated by JetifRex, although an answer has been accepted. The function $x^2-k(x-\ln(1+x))$ is less than $0$ for small $x$ whenever $k>1$. Thus for sufficiently large $N$, for all $n\geq N$, we would have $a_n^2\leq k(a_n-\ln(1+a_n))$.

Note first that $a_n \to 0$.
Now $\frac {x- \ln (1+x)} {x^{2}} \to \frac  1 2$ as $ x\to 0$ and  the series $\sum (a_n-\ln (1+a_n))$ (whose terms are necessarily positive after some stage)  converges. This implies that $\sum a_n^{2}$ converges too.

Since $a_n \to 0$, by discarding a finitely many terms if necessary, we may assume that $|a_n| < 1$ for all $n$ without affecting the convergence of any of the series involved.
Now, let $f(x) = x - \log(1 + x)$. Then by the Taylor's theorem, for $|x| < 1$, there exists $\xi$ between $0$ and $x$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= f(0) + f'(0)x + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2} x^2
= \frac{x^2}{2(1+\xi)^2}
\geq \frac{x^2}{8}.
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 8(a_n - \log(1+a_n)) $$
and since the right-hand side is finite, the desired concolusion follows from the comparison test.
